Is there any way to detect SIM insertion on iOS 16 and later?
I am developing an iOS application where I need to detect if a SIM card is inserted in the device. I am targeting iOS 16 and later. I have tried using CTTelephonyNetworkInfo and CTSubscriber, but I am encountering issues with permissions and API availability.
Here is what I have tried so far:
Info.plist Configuration
I have added the necessary keys to my Info.plist:
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your location to determine network availability.</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your location to determine network availability.</string>

import UIKit
import CoreTelephony
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the delegate and request location services permissions
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        // Check SIM availability
        let simStatus = checkSimAvailability()
        print(simStatus)
    }
    
    func checkSimAvailability() -> String {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            let subscriber = CTSubscriber()
            if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
                do {
                    if subscriber.isSIMInserted {
                        return "SIM card is inserted."
                    } else {
                        return "No SIM card detected."
                    }
                } catch {
                    return "Error determining if SIM is inserted: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                }
            } else {
                return "isSIMInserted is only available on iOS 18.0 or newer."
            }
        } else {
            return "isSIMInserted is only available on iOS 16.0 or newer."
        }
        
        if let carriers = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders,
           let carrier = carriers.first?.value,
           let _ = carrier.mobileNetworkCode {
            return "SIM card is available.\nCarrier Name: \(carrier.carrierName ?? "None")"
        } else {
            return "No SIM card installed"
        }
    }

    // CLLocationManagerDelegate
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            print("Location services authorized.")
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("Location services denied or restricted.")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Location services permission not determined yet.")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown case.")
        }
    }
}

When I run this code on iOS 18 beta 3, I get the following error:

Error determining if SIM is inserted: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"

In addition i also added the following in info.plist
<key>NSCTTelephonyUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to cellular provider information to detect the presence of a SIM card.</string>
    
    <key>SIMSupportedNetworks</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>MCC</key>
            <string>525</string>
            <key>MNC</key>
            <string>01</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>MCC</key>
            <string>525</string>
            <key>MNC</key>
            <string>02</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>MCC</key>
            <string>525</string>
            <key>MNC</key>
            <string>07</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.coretelephony.sim-inserted</key>
    <true/>

